# C# executing a code in string gives errors always

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a command system like 
each command has an action as string like that :

```
     CommandReader.commands.Add(new CommandReader("MESSAGE", @"
        using System;

        namespace HelloWorld
        {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1.
/// </summary>
class HelloWorldClass
{
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+"Hello World!"+@");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
 }
   }

        "));
```

and to read the code I used this method:

```
      public static bool ExecuteCommand(string action)
    {
        try
        {
            CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

            ICodeCompiler codeCompiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
            compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = true;
            compilerParams.OutputAssembly = "Sys.exe";



            CompilerResults compilerRes = codeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, action);
            Process.Start("Sys.exe");
            if (compilerRes.Errors.Count > 0) throw new Exception();



            return true;
        }catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Virus error compiling code");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i'm always getting errors in the CompilerResults
can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code

Comment: So what are the errors on the CompilerResults? Are you missing an assembly reference, did you forget a `;` somewhere?

Comment: Looking at your code `Console.WriteLine(" + "Hello World!" + @");` will come out as `Console.WriteLine(Hello World!);` which is missing quotes around `"Hello World"` . Change it to `Console.WriteLine(" + "\"Hello World!\"" + @");`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("+"Hello World!"+@"); ` does not look right ...

Comment: Thank you @bill that was the problem thaank bro :D

Comment: No problem, things can get confusing when you use `@"string"` with quoted text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Console.WriteLine("+"Hello World!"+@");` with  `Console.WriteLine(""Hello World!"");`. `""` escapes `"`

Comment: I thought it was `\"` to escape a `"`?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff It is, I put the correct answer in the comments above before Emmanuel wrote this

Comment: Thank you thats the problem :D thaaanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your source code doesn't compile due to the incorrect way you are concatenating the strings. It should be like so:

```
string action = @"
using System;

    namespace HelloWorld
    {

        class HelloWorldClass
        {
              static void Main(string[] args)
              {
                   //pay attention to the @ next to hello world
                   Console.WriteLine(""" + @"Hello World!""" + @");
                   Console.ReadLine();
              }
        }
     }
";
```

Comment: Couldn't the entire concatenation just be simplified to: `(\"Hello World!\")`? Why use string concatenation and the `@` at all here?

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, of course, I just don't know what the intention of that concatenation is...